# How to fix ValueError: Invalid Literal for int() with base 10: " " in my code

Tags: python

I am currently trying to program some code that converts RLE inputted by a user and stored in a file into its decompressed form however I keep getting the same error no matter what I try and change

I have tried everything that I can think of myself and have spent a while looking at questions asked by people with the same problem however all of the solutions I have tried have been ineffective so far

```
  def EnterRle():
      lines = int(input("How many lines of RLE do you wish to input?"))
      if lines<=2:
          print("ERROR, NOT ENOUGH LINES")
          EnterRle()
      for i in range(1,lines + 1):
          f = open("CUSTOMRLE.txt","a")
          RLE = input("Please input line " + str(i) + " of RLE:")
      f.write(RLE) 
      f.write("\n")
      f.close()
      f = open("CUSTOMRLE.txt","r")
      X = f.read()
      Ascii = decode(X)
      print(Ascii) 


  def decode(X):
      ret_str = ""
      index = 0
      if X != "":
          while (index < len(X)):
              first = ""
              while (X[index] in "01234567829"):
                  first += X[index]
                  index += 1
                  num = int(first)

                  ch = X[index]
              index += 1
              ret_str += ch*num
          os.remove("CUSTOMRLE.txt")
          return (ret_str)
```

I have tried the decode code with just a normal input and it has worked fine however whenever I try to do it using the file it prints the error ValueError: Invalid literal for int() with base 10: " " I have no idea what is causing this error and any help would be appreciated

Comment: `int("")` produces this error.  I see a `while` loop that initials `first`, and later does `int(first)`.  That could be producing this error.  By the way, did you pay attention to the traceback, which should have told you which line produced the error?

Comment: print `first` before the assignment and you should find some invalid literal as an argument to `int`